# Executing Rscript from a Batch file - can't process "Umlaute" (ä, ö, ü) properly

Tags: r, batch-file

I have an Rscript which executes just fine when i do it within RStudio. If i execute the same Rscript via a batch-file, it can't process the german "Umlaute" (ä, ö, ü).

- The RScript is saved as UTF-8
- The default text encoding is set to UTF-8
- I tried adding *CHCP 65001* and *chcp 1252* to the batch-file, with same result, like this:

```
CHCP 65001
"C:/Users/John Doe/Documents/R/R-4.0.5/bin/Rscript.exe" "uebel.R"
pause
```

Is it a problem with batch? What can i do to avoid it?

In my case it wouldn't work to just remove all the "Umlaute". Technically, it would, but not practically.

---

Very simple example:

RScript, saved as "uebel.R":

```
übel <- 1+1
```

batch-file, saved as: "uebel.bat":

```
"C:/Users/John Doe/Documents/R/R-4.0.5/bin/Rscript.exe" "uebel.R"
pause
```

Gives the me Error in the cmd:

```
Fehler: unerwartete Eingabe in "Ã¼" (Error: unexpected input in "Ã¼")
```

---

Another example in the Rscript and what i receive in cmd:

```
cat("übelkeit")
```

```
Ã¼belkeit
```

Comment: Have you tried to add 'options(encoding = "UTF-8")' ad the top of your script?

Comment: Yes, does not change anything.

Comment: @Dutschke i have an idea

Comment: @Dutschke, you are telling us things which do not exist in your question area. Please use the [edit] option, to make sure that the information about the encoding option for your RScript is included, the batch file is included, and sufficient information for everyone interested to reproduce your issue. The comment area is not where we are supposed to search for additional information in order to offer our assistance, everything we need should be clear in your question body itself.

Comment: I dont see where i told you things that dont exist in my question. I tried Julians solution after he proposed it and it failed. I gave information about the encoding. What else do you need? I understand it might be hard to reproduce because i get this error on my PC but i tried my best giving all information that i thought are necessary.

Comment: @Dutschke, you edit is not good enough, you've told us that you've used the `chcp` command, but it does not exist in your submission. Also you've commented that you've used `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` in your RScript, but it does not exist in your submission. We need to be able to execute an `RScript` matching yours, from a batch file matching yours, and reproduce your error. That is not possible with what you've submitted, so please include that information for us to have a [mcve] and tell us exactly what encoding both of your scripts have been saved as, and what your locale codepage is.

Comment: How about now? I added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling with

```
"C:/Users/John Doe/Documents/R/R-4.0.5/bin/Rscript.exe" --encoding="UTF-8" "uebel.R"
```

Comment: This is what the cmd gives me: "file name is missing"

Comment: @Dutschke weird, was able to reproduce your issue on ``R-4.0.2``, but encoding line passed.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i forgot to also paste the "8". It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's also a solution using the package **"ds4psy"** for printing umlauts:

**An example:**

```
library(ds4psy)
cat (Umlaut["U"],"belkeit", sep = "")
Übelkeit
```